# Find value that is substring in a column - if found put substring in another column of that row

Tags: excel, vba

Apologies if the title is poorly worded, not sure how to approach this.
I have limited knowledge of VBA in excel.

I want to find a substring of text in column A and place it in column B so my data will look something like this if I am looking for the keyword "blue":

```
A         |       B
---------- ----------
red ball  | 
blue ball |  blue
fox blue  |  blue
```

Comment: you can try by using **Google** to read about `String` functions, like `Instr` , `Split` and `Replace` , these will give you a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a formula, no VBA required. In B1

```
=if(isnumber(search("blue",A1)),"blue","")
```

Search is not case sensitive. If you want the formula to be case sensitive, use Find() instead.